# Is it okay to judge projects on the basis of how long it took to develop them

Tags: grading, projects, evaluation-criteria

I was showing my presentation on a project which I made in java/javafx to this evaluator(i'm a college student). And before I could start explaining the usage he asked me how much time did I spend on this project and I told him i did it in 20 days(which i think is a lot) . He then told me that I need to atleast spend 6 months on a project [*reason being that we have 12 months to study a language which was a lie we had 9 months actually* ]  and asked me to leave. He didn't even let me finish the presentation or saw what I did. So, what i'd like to know is this fair to judge a project like this or the evaluator was being unfair?

Comment: Who is _he_? Please clarify.

Comment: @scaaahu The project evaluator who our college hired to judge the projects.

Comment: Please clarify if he is the professor who teaches the course? The TA who helps the professor? Or someone your college hired temporily as consultant?

Comment: Well it's a fair question if what he/she saw was poor.  I have said pretty much the same thing to students who didn't put in the effort.   Basically, you haven't done enough work.  Thanks for playing.

Comment: @Prof.SantaClaus I agree what you're saying. But the only problem in my case is that he didn't even saw what i did so he could evaluate the effort. He simply asked how much time i spend on the project and then asked me to leave. I'd have no problem if he had see and say that the effort wasn't enough or the project isn't good.

Comment: @scaaahu He was hired temporarily as a consultant/evaluator.

Comment: When did the presentation happen? At the end of the 9 months?

Comment: @scaaahu yes it did happened at the end of 9 months.

Comment: Another question, before the presentation, did you put the project somewhere so others can see it? Is there any chance he could have seen it already?

Comment: @scaaahu No sir.

Comment: In the end, it will be difficult to ascertain this from a simple Stackexchange post, but I would consider it extremely problematic if the time spent is actively judged. - A good programmer is a LOT faster than a novice programmer (maybe even a bad one). So you have a programming job/project and finish it quickly due to prior experience: Should it be graded worse because you are faster? - What should be evaluated is the content, not the time taken. Case in point, I remember implementing the enigma encryption in VBA during my maths degree as coursework - someone else wrote their thesis on it.

Comment: Now I did not read the thesis and I hope it contained more details on how enigma was cracked too, calculations on complexity etc. - But the implementation part is - in reality - nowadays pretty trivial.

Comment: Orders of magnitude usually matter. However, I doubt the question would have appeared if the software were satisfactory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Charitably, it sounds like you put in about 200 hours of work during a nine-month period. That works out to maybe five to six hours per week. That may not meet the minimum “level of effort” expected for such a project. The evaluator may be well within his rights to terminate the evaluation at that point, particularly if this is a “project course” that amounts to a significant portion of your total credit load for the semester. Is it fair to do so? Probably not. Is it allowed to so? Quite possibly.

Comment: To the downvoter, I failed to see the wrongness of this answer. Would you care to explain?

Comment: @scaaahu The voter might just not like the answer. Unfortunately grading is one of those imperfect messy things that will always be ugly and messy.